# NSTableView grouping

Tags: swift

I am trying to add groups to my NSTableView. I found this function:

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, isGroupRow row: Int) -> Bool
{
    if (row == 5)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Which works great. Row 5 is a group after that. But I am not sure how to add a title to that?

I am using a custom view:

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView?
{
    if (row == 5)
    {
        ??????
    }

    let result : CellViewCustom = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier(tableColumn!.identifier, owner: self) as! CellViewCustom

    ...

    return result
}
```

But in row 5 it says tableColumn == nil

How do I add text to the group header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike in iOS, the group cells of `NSTableView` are "inline" in the (non-nested) data source array.

**Simple example**

- A custom struct `Item` with property `name`, `title` and `isGroup`. All instances whose `title` is not empty are group rows

  ```
  struct Item {

    let name, title : String
    let isGroup : Bool

    init(name : String, title : String = "") {
      self.name = name
      self.title = title
      self.isGroup = !title.isEmpty
    }
  }
  ```
- Create a data source array and assign 2 group and 3 normal rows

  ```
  var items = [Item]()

  ...

  items = [Item(name:"", title:"Group 1"), 
           Item(name:"bar"), 
           Item(name:"baz"), 
           Item(name:"", title:"Group 2"), 
           Item(name:"zab")]
  ```
- In `isGroupRow` just return the value of the property

  ```
  func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, isGroupRow row: Int) -> Bool
  {
    return items[row].isGroup
  }
  ```
- In `viewForTableColumn` create two different views for group and table row

  ```
  func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView?
  {
    let item = items[row]
    if item.isGroup {
      let groupCell = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier("GroupCell", owner:self) as! NSTableCellView
      groupCell.textField!.stringValue = item.title
      return cell
    } else {
      let cell = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier(tableColumn!.identifier, owner: self) as! CellViewCustom

      ...

      return cell
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the code. It looks great but I have a problem. `tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier("GroupCell", owner:self)` returns nil. I am not sure why?

Comment: The code assumes there is a second prototype cell in the table view in Interface Builder with identifier "GroupCell"